# Why is there "Uncaught SyntaxError" when I do $http.post({ })?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin")
    .constant("authUrl", "http://localhost:5500/users/login")
    .controller("authCtrl", function($scope,$http,$location,authUrl){

        $scope.authenticate = function (user, pass){
            $http.post(authUrl,{
                username: user,
                password: pass
            }, {
                withCredentials:true
            }).success(function (data){
                $location.path("/main");
            }).error(function (error){
                $scope.authenticationError = error;
            });
        }
    });
```

When I do this code, I have this in console.

> SyntaxError:     at fromJson (/angular.js:1103:3)
>   at defaultHttpResponseTransform
>   (/angular.js:8572:11)    at Anonymous function
>   (/angular.js:8517:5)    at forEach
>   (/angular.js:335:11)    at transformData
>   (/angular.js:8516:3)    at transformResponse
>   (/angular.js:9224:11)    at processQueue
>   (/angular.js:12914:11)    at Anonymous function
>   (/angular.js:12930:27)    at
>   Scope.prototype.$eval (/angular.js:14123:9)    at
>   Scope.prototype.$digest (/angular.js:13939:15)

What's the problem?
Is there any problem in my $http.post code?

Comment: what is the response from authUrl?

Comment: The problem is with the response from the server, and not the code that made the request. Look at the JSON and ensure it's in a valid format. Use this tool: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Is authurl a strong?

Comment: I'm reading a book called "Pro Angular JS" , and the code above is from that book. The code I wrote is same as the book's code.